# Predict set of location points at a single time slot

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

The sample dataset contains Location point of the user.

```
df.head()

   user           tslot         Location_point
0   0   2015-12-04 13:00:00     4356
1   0   2015-12-04 13:15:00     4356
2   0   2015-12-04 13:30:00     3659
3   0   2015-12-04 13:45:00     4356
4   0   2015-12-04 14:00:00     8563

df.shape 

(576,3)
```

The location points are random and need to predict the next location point of the user for a given time. As the location points are random numbers I need to predict the set of location points at each time slot.

```
Example:

If I need to predict the location point at tslot 2015-12-04 14:00:00.
my predicted output should be [8563,4356,3659,5861,3486].
```

My code

```
time_steps=1
data_dim = X_train.shape[2]
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(data_dim, input_shape=(time_steps,data_dim), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(data_dim))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=96)
model.summary()
```

which helps to to predict 1 location points for each time slot. I would like to know if this is possible and how?

Comment: I am confused. At each time t, are you trying to predict he location at t, t-1, t-2, ... or are you trying to make multiple predictions and like use the mean to be more accurate? Or sth else?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to make multiple predictions for each time slots.

Comment: Then, are you trying to obtain some notion of uncertainty around your predictions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that that this is for gaining some confidence about the predictions.

If this is the case, there are multiple ways to do this. For example, refer to [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.11053.pdf) paper by Amazon on how to predict quantiles, and [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.01907.pdf) paper on how to use a Bayesian framework to obtain uncertainty around the predictions.

If you have other intentions, please clarify.

Comment: Hello, Sorry for the late reply. I am new to neural networks. Can you help me with some sample code?